# Can't login to phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, centos

I am new at linux but I beed phpmyadmin on my centos server. I did this:

```
cd /var/www/html/ (document root of apache)
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmyadmin/path/to/latest/version
tar xvfz phpMyAdmin-3.3.9-all-languages.tar.gz 
mv phpMyAdmin-3.3.9-all-languages  phpmyadmin
rm phpMyAdmin-3.3.9-all-languages.tar.gz 
cd phpmyadmin/
cp config.sample.inc.php config.inc.php
```

When I go to www.$ip/phpmyadmin and I am presented with a login screen asking for username and password. How can I get these credentials to log in? I'd like to log in as root I guess. But I don't know how to setup a root account and create a password for root using the cli and mysql. Please help? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

To set the mysql root password try the following:

```
 $ mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASSWORD
```

If you've never set the mysql password before, you won't have a password yet.
Also it's important to remember that the mysql root user and the system root user are different. (And they should have different passwords)

More information is available from here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mysql-change-root-password/

Comment: ok i type mysql.. then when i type your command i just get an indented arrow... nothing happens.

Comment: The mysqladmin command is supposed to be run directly from the shell, not from within mysql.  You might also be running into problems from your shell environment.  Could you post the output you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with making login by phpMyAdmin with new user which I was created in phpMyAdmin as root. I added the new user with all ALL PRIVILEGES and there was no effect.

Finally, I created the new user by MySQL Command Line Shell and everything became all right.

I did it by following commands:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'new_username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password_for_new_user';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I found the description [HERE](http://corpocrat.com/2008/09/28/how-to-create-new-user-for-phpmyadmin-login/)

Answer (score 0):

You are logging in to MySQL through phpMyAdmin, so the username and password you use would be the MySQL username and password.

Comment: yes but i only just installed mysql using yum mysql mysql-server and php-mysql... i don't have any user accounts and don't know how to create them. If i allow login without password in the config file then i can login without username or password but it takes me to a blank page which says <end>

Comment: @user - Try logging in using the command line client and set the password for root first, then try phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

From the default setup, it should be a username and password from the MySQL database itself.  So if you have a user account for the MySQL database, use that.